# How can I tell if my server is running Ubuntu as 64-bit or 32-bit

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine Linux Server’s Architecture (32 or 64 bit)](https://serverfault.com/questions/61673/determine-linux-servers-architecture-32-or-64-bit)

I want to install a package and it has a version for 32-bit ubuntu and 64-bit. How can I tell which one is running on my server?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/27590/how-do-i-know-if-i-am-running-32-or-64-bit-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the version of the **package** and not the version of the server, do either one of the following commands:

```
dpkg -s <packagename>
dpkg -p <packagename>
```

to print out the details of the package. For example, it will look like this:

```
$ dpkg -s zip
Package: zip
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 644
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.0-1ubuntu1
Replaces: zip-crypt (<= 2.30-2)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7)
Recommends: unzip
Conflicts: zip-crypt (<= 2.30-2)
Description: Archiver for .zip files
 This is InfoZIP's zip program. It produces files that are fully
 compatible with the popular PKZIP program; however, the command line
 options are not identical. In other words, the end result is the same,
 but the methods differ. :-)
 .
 This version supports encryption.
Original-Maintainer: Santiago Vila <sanvila@debian.org>
```

Answer (score 1):

You know when you're typing out a question it lists similar ones? Well it makes sense to look at them in case the question has been asked before;

[Determine Linux Server's Architecture (32 or 64 bit)](https://serverfault.com/questions/61673/determine-linux-servers-architecture-32-or-64-bit)

Comment: How about contributing a vote to close as exact duplicate?

Comment: Nah, making snarky comments-as-answers is far more fun.

Comment: Sorry farseeker I was posting from my phone (in bed too, which is quite sad really) and it's quite complex to do that in that way.

Comment: You can't post a comment from your phone, but you can look up a dupe and post an answer?  That's one weird phone.

Comment: You misunderstand, for some reason my iphone struggles to deal with closing, not commenting or posting - it could be a user error :)

Answer (score 0):

um.. if anyone else wants to know, I figured it out:

```
uname -m
```

Comment: even better.... +1

Answer (score 0):

use the command

uname -a

read the string.  It will be near the end.  Example:

Linux ora100 2.6.5-7.252-smp #1 SMP Tue Feb 14 11:11:04 UTC 2006 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: On what distribution did you get that result?  I get a different result than yours but all the same from my laptop and three of my servers.  Or is the fact that it says i686 the give away to 32 bit?

[Mepis]
Linux MOBIL-01 2.6.27-1-mepis-smp #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 12 21:22:47 EDT 2009 i686 GNU/Linux

[CentOS]
Linux SHODAN 2.6.18-164.9.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Dec 15 21:04:57 EST 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

[two X Debian]
Linux BOSS 2.6.26-2-486 #1 Wed Nov 4 20:19:07 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
Linux ARDVARC 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Wed Nov 4 20:45:37 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64bit server, it can run either one (32 or 64) but I would stick with 64bit whenever possible. And Ubuntu usually sticks with the one that it was installed with in my case.