# Linux + how to verify linux version 32 Bit or 64 Bit

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know if I am running 32 or 64-bit Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/27590/how-do-i-know-if-i-am-running-32-or-64-bit-linux)
>   [Determine Linux Server's Architecture (32 or 64 bit)](https://serverfault.com/questions/61673/determine-linux-servers-architecture-32-or-64-bit)

I installed the following

- RedHat-Linux-OS-5.3.0.0-01_x32 on machine1
- RedHat-Linux-OS-5.3.0.0-01_x64 on machine2

What command or file can I use to check if the version of Linux installed is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Note that redhat-release does not define whether the version is 32/64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the current running 'arch' (architecture), run:

```
uname -m
```

Capability of your CPUs you can run:

```
dmidecode
```

and

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

The '*LM*' flag should be present in 64bits systems as it represent 'LONG MODE' (64bit Extensions, AMD’s AMD64 or Intel’s EM64T).

Answer (score 4):

Typing   uname -m in a shell will do.