# How do you install a JDK6 on Solaris10 sparc 64bits?

Tags: installation, solaris, java

The installation steps of a JDK6 for:

- [**Solaris 32 bits**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/install/jdk/install-solaris.html)
- [**Solaris 64 bits**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/install/jdk/install-solaris-64.html)

are quite straightforward but:

- are in two separate documents
- do not deal with [local zone (container)](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/zones/index.jsp) installation
- do not address fully non-standard installation path

The answer below is a community-wiki one, meant to be edited.

Do you have any comments/remarks we all should know when installing  JDK on a Solaris10 sparc server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 2009 (time of my [first answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/71268/how-do-you-install-a-jdk6-on-solaris10-sparc-64bits/71269#71269)), I found out that the self-extracting scripts were perfectly compatible with non-standard path (like installing a JDK in a user's `$HOME/usr/local` for instance, instead of the system path `/usr/local`)

The latest [Oracle JDK download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u26-download-400750.html) lists:

```
Solaris SPARC - Self Extracting Binary        86.05 MB  jdk-6u26-solaris-sparc.sh
Solaris SPARC 64-bit - Self Extracting Binary 12.24 MB  jdk-6u26-solaris-sparcv9.sh
```

You need to be careful if you copy them from Windows to your server (with **[winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/screenshots)** for instance): you need to copy those two `sh` scripts **[as binary](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_mode)** (or they won't work once copied on the Unix server).

Once on the server, you need to `chmod 755` the two `.sh` (the second being needed only if you have a [64-bit Solaris](https://serverfault.com/questions/27590/how-do-i-know-if-i-am-running-32-or-64-bit-linux/202807#202807)).
Execute them both (for instance in `$HOME/usr/local`, as the user **without needing any root privilege**), first `jdk-6u26-solaris-sparc.sh`, then if needed `jdk-6u26-solaris-sparcv9.sh`.

That will create a `$HOME/usr/local/jdf1.6.0_26` in which you have a fully operation JDK.

- no root right necessary (contrary to `pkgadd`)
- no environment variable modified: you will need to add `$HOME/usr/local/jdf1.6.0_26/bin` to your `$PATH` if you want to use that particular JDK, but the point is:
  this installation won't disturb any of your current environment settings.
  (note: the `JAVA_HOME` isn't set of course, but [it never is by any installation process anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560797/why-doesnt-the-java-sdk-installer-set-java-home/560847#560847))

Answer (score 1):

Update 2011: see my [updated answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/71268/how-do-you-install-a-jdk6-on-solaris10-sparc-64bits/281817#281817): no more `sudo pkgadd` necessary.

---

First answer in 2009:

There are two methods for installing a JDK:

- Self-extracting binary (shell script)
- Solaris packages (`pkgadd` command)

Since the Self-extracting binary is not meant to be configured to install in non-standard path, I would recommend the later one (packages).

You need to [**download**](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp):

- **jdk-6u16-solaris-sparc.tar.Z** (main package, used for 32-bits installation)
- **jdk-6u16-solaris-sparcv9.tar.Z** (small package, used for 64-bits additional-step installation)

Since the content extraction of those compressed archives creates files directly in the current directory, I would advise moving each archive in its dedicated repository

```
$ mkdir jdk-6u16-solaris-sparc
$ mv jdk-6u16-solaris-sparc.tar.Z jdk-6u16-solaris-sparc
$ cd jdk-6u16-solaris-sparc
$ zcat jdk-6<update>-solaris-sparc.tar.Z | tar -xf -
$ cd ..
$ mkdir jdk-6u16-solaris-sparcv9
$ mv jdk-6u16-solaris-sparcv9.tar.Z jdk-6u16-solaris-sparcv9
$ cd jdk-6u16-solaris-sparcv9
$ zcat jdk-6<update>-solaris-sparcv9.tar.Z | tar -xf -
```

What is not mentioned in the documentation is the case when you need a local installation (in a local zone), separate from a global JDK already installed in `/usr/java` (`/usr` is not writable from a local zone).

the '`-R`' option of pkgadd comes in handy in this case.

```
$ cd jdk-6u16-solaris-sparc
$ sudo pkgadd -R /MY_REP -d . SUNWj6rt SUNWj6dev SUNWj6cfg SUNWj6man SUNWj6dmo
$ cd ../jdk-6u16-solaris-sparcv9
$ sudo pkgadd -R /MY_REP -d . SUNWj6rtx SUNWj6dvx SUNWj6dmx
```

Here JDK6 is installed under:

```
/MY_REP/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0

/MY_REP/usr/java -> jdk/jdk1.6.0_16/
/MY_REP/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_16 -> instances/jdk1.6.0/
```

No need to "root shell" (which is 'evil' anyway) as mentioned by the Sun documentation:
a '`sudo root pkgadd`' is enough.