# I have a rackspace cloud server. How to check if it is 64 bit or 32 bit?

Tags: linux

What command do I type in to check this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this a Linux server?  If so, try `uname -p`

Example:

```
$ uname -p
x86_64
```

Note that this only tells you about the Linux kernel, not any particular user-land software (e.g. you can still run 32-bit MySQL on 64-bit Linux).  *And* you could be running 32-bit Linux on a 64-bit CPU.

Comment: D'oh.  I just saw the "linux" tag, so of course it's a Linux server :-).

Answer (score 2):

You could also check the cpuinfo and look for the "lm" (long mode) flag

> less /proc/cpuinfo

output:

> flags           : ... lm ....

a 32-bit processor won't have this flag.

Comment: Could be a 32-bit distribution on a 64-bit processor

Comment: Look at this thread:
http://serverfault.com/questions/27590/how-do-i-know-if-i-am-running-32-or-64-bit-linux

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Matt's answer about your kernel, if you're running a Red Hat/CentOS RPM-based distro (which is what most of Rackspace is, typically) you can check the installed userland tools for their bitness with this command:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat='%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n' | sort
```

You're looking for .i386 or .x86_64 on the end. It's entirely possible to have a mix of 32bit and 64bit on a 64bit install based on needs of the server.